# JS get the position of element based on the body when position absolute on element

Tags: javascript, css

I need to build a tooltip, but I need to position the tooltip based on the body because its position is absolute and I don't want any relative parent to break my style.

```
 <div style="position: relative;">
    <input>
    <p class="tooltip">tooltip</p>
 </div>
```

I need the tooltip to be on the input but always relative to the body.

How can I calc this?

Comment: What is `class="position: relative;"`? Do you mean `style="position: relative;"`?

Comment: Yes, my mistake thanks

Comment: wrap input + tooltip into a div??

Answer (score 0):

Elements with `position: absolute` are always realtive to the first parent Element with `relative`. (or anything except static and fixed)

So to fix it you need to avoid using `position: relative` on the parent

```
<div>
   <input>
   <p class="tooltip">tooltip</p>
</div>
```

or since it's anyways `absolute` positioned move the tooltip out of the relative element.

```
<p class="tooltip">tooltip</p>
<div style="position: relative;">
   <input>
</div>
```

Comment: I can't I need the tooltip to be at the bottom of the input

Comment: Ok. I think there are just these two ways to do that. css parents or markup or `position fixed` if this is the approach you want

Answer (score 0):

Using `position:absolute;` should position the tooltip relative to the nearest positioned element—in this case, the `div` marked `position:relative;`. (See the [CSS3 reference on absolute positioning](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp).)

So in your example, you don't need to worry about any parent elements with relative positioning, as they shouldn't affect the absolute positioning context. You should be able to simply use:

```
<div style="position: relative;">
  <input>
  <p class="tooltip" style="position:absolute; top:0; left:0;>tooltip</p>
</div>
```

Unless I'm misunderstanding your question, in which case, please provide more detailed examples.

EDIT:

If you're trying to avoid using `position: relative`, you can set the tooltip position with javascript:

```
var input = document.getElementById('input-id');
var tooltip = document.getElementById('tooltip-id');

tooltip.style.left = (input.offsetLeft)+'px';
tooltip.style.top = (input.offsetTop)+'px';
```

Comment: I need to position the element based on the body. Like I don't have any other relative parent in my way.

Answer (score -1):

change class to style:

```
<div>
  <input>
  <p class="tooltip" style="position:relative;">tooltip</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Read the question please

Comment: If you want your tooltip to be positioned relatively, set the `position:relative;` style to your tooltip - see changed code